# How to test android application on a PC

Tags: android, testing

I have an application (simple calc app) developed myself using android eclipse. It's working fine on my system and I want to test the apk file on another PC. But I don't know exactly what the requirements are for the other PC, and how to add my apk file to another system for testing.

What do I need to do?

Comment: Instead of testing in another pc, test in device . Because no one can test your application on his pc .

Comment: Just save your project and move its folder to another pc's eclipse workspace, but what's the point of testing android app with another pc?

Comment: yes u r wright my , i my concern v hav no device thats y v jus test in pc first

Comment: Testing in another PC won't help you. What you need to do is to create more emulators of different devices with different screen sizes and OS version and test your app on that. This is still not as good as testing on a device but it's a start. If you do want to install it in another system, install android sdk there.

Answer (score 0):

copy your android sdk into into another pc and use ADB command to create/start new emulator.
After that you can use ADB command to install your APK on emulator.

ADB command reference :http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html

Comment: But testing on another pc is not right wayto test ur application.u hv to do it on device.

Answer (score 0):

Create an APK (Signed Or UnSigned)of your app. And Open Eclipse Go to DDMS Perspective and Push your APK to the system Folder.

And Then Run.

Comment: how to Push  APK to the system Folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an app named BlueStacks where you can install some apps to test and to use. Despite of it's in beta phase it

This app is faster than the Android Virtual Machine that goes with the Android SDK.